# "Start was unexpected at this time"

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file with the code below:

```bash
@echo off
:takeinput
set input=
echo.
set /p input=%cd%^>
call :emptycheck %input%

:emptycheck
if [%1]==[] goto takeinput
call :detect %input%
:detect
if /i %1==chrisutil call :chrisutil %input%
%input%
goto takeinput

:chrisutil
if [%2]==[] powershell.exe -command "iwr -useb https://christitus.com/win | iex"
if /i %2==web start www.christitus.com/windows-tool & goto takeinput
if errorlevel 1 (
echo Something bad happened.
)
goto takeinput
```

So, if i type `CHRISUTIL` it should execute a powershell command:

```bash
powershell.exe -command "iwr -useb https://christitus.com/win | iex"
```

If I type `CHRISUTIL web` it should open `www.christitus.com/windows-tool` on my browser.

Can someone tell me what I did wrong here, because `CHRISUTIL web` works. but `CHRISUTIL` results in:

```
Start was unexpected at this time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem:

when the execution hits `if [%2]==[]`
if does invoke `powershell.exe -command ...` but *then* it continues with `if /i %2==web` which fails as erroneous syntax because `%2` is empty.

the solution:

quit after the powershell command
either add `& exit` or `& goto :eof` or add those in a second line after powershell in parenthesized block

or use the recommended syntax for the comparison `if /i "%~2" == "web"`

Comment: using your solution, i separated the `if errorlevel 1 (` part to another loop then add `& goto loop` after the powershell command, it is running perfectly. thank you so much! :D

Comment: @Stephan added your suggestion to the answer